# Using a ISO language code when making subtitles default

Tags: subtitle, mkv

I'm making a program using AHK and MKVtoolnix to remove audio file and subtitles quickly here's the code:

```
FOR /F "delims=*" %%A IN ('dir /b *.MKV') DO "H:\Not School\Programs\mkvtoolnix-32-bit-15.0.0\mkvtoolnix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%OutputVar%\%%A" -a %AT% -s %ST% --default-subtitle ???  "%InputVar%\%%A
```

When I put an ISO code in where the question marks are I get an error, and I'd like to have it the same as %ST% which will be the subtitles I'm keeping, is there anyway round this or am I going to have to add a input box for subtitle track?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option named `--default-subtitle`. Are you thinking of `--default-language`?

Anyway, if you are merely copying subtitle tracks that already have a language set (as you make it sound), mkvmerge will copy the language information, so you don’t need to override it. Just remove the `--default-subtitle ???`, and you’re good to go.